# How do I code a toggle-able variable with a button in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have this code here. All it does is when I have a button I've wired in pushed down, it prints "Button Pressed" every .3 seconds. I've tried everything, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to make it so this button toggles a variable between True and False, or 0,1 , etc... I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks

```
 import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


while True:
    inputValue = GPIO.input(18)
    if (inputValue == False):
        print("Button press ")
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Something exactly like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH3hNLXxNeE

Comment: Why you tag `robotics` ?!

Comment: Has to do with electronics and programming... @arman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know if the state of the button has changed.

You need to keep track of the state and compare it when you get a new value from the `GPIO`.

```
latest_state = None

while True:
    inputValue = GPIO.input(18)
    if inputValue != latest_state:
        latest_state = inputValue
        if latest_state:
            print("Button pressed")
        else:
            print("Button depressed")
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> x = True
>>> x
True

>>> x = not x
>>> x
False

>>> x = not x
>>> x
True
```

Whenever the button is pressed, you can set whatever you're using as a Boolean variable (`inputValue`?) equal to `not [variable]`.  I don't quite understand what you're doing in your code, but here's some pseudocode:

```
Boolean switch = False
if button is pressed:
    switch = not switch
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are proposing.

Comment: `Boolean switch = False` is not valid Python

Comment: As I said, it's not meant to be Python code, just pseudocode.  I wasn't sure how to have the conditional `if button is pressed` using the Python libraries OP is using